# google sheets "sum" not working on a column full of query result

Tags: google-sheets-formula, spreadsheet

I have a column filled with this query.
={QUERY(asientos!B1:F198;"select C,D where B = "&B2;0)}
[data source](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SO2Y9.png) the query will look for the data here.
There is no problem yet
this is the result and it's fine
[query fill data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YsN5o.png)

the problem is that I can't add the first column, surprisingly the second column works fine
[see the formula](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dKIU5.png)
[without adding numbers on the left column, but the right](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OAwTg.png)
[don't know why](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CdQWT.png)

here is the sheet
https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1dgiXBBFEyJzijSsJrrSlm7WcR1znPO9OSNV0TiKua_A/edit?usp=sharing

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vTWpTmhZbJ-6pdai6s780M3dGzaZaTHvML_J2pQGL6IWfl3Ar7Mb16UdSVkIm1upc2xOQ1Lxe-IG1b5/pubhtml

I would have to be able to add the left and right clolumns, not only one. I don't know why doesn't work or how to resolve the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

*`query()` does not react well with mixed data-types present in a single column. Your `asientos` columns `C` & `D` which you are referencing within the query is full on loaded with mixed data-types (numerical & text) which is resulting in this ruckus. **[this article here](https://infoinspired.com/google-docs/spreadsheet/mixed-data-type-issue-in-query/)** gives a detailed explanation on what is this issue & how to deal with it and all...*

*alternatively you could use this in `mayor!B4` instead:*

```js
=filter(asientos!C1:D198;asientos!B1:B198=B2)
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you, filter works well for my purposes, I don't need to fix data on the query